# React Redux dispatch method redirect to white screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Im implementing redux in my react native app, I need to create 2 reducers, one of them is designed to manage login state and the other to manage some process status.

Reducers:

- isLogged
- processStatus

processStatus Actions:

```js
export function start() {
    return {
        type: 'START_LOADING'
    }
}

export function stop() {
    return {
        type: 'END_LOADING'
    }
}
```

isLogged Actions:

```js
export function signIn() {
    return {
        type: 'SIGN_IN'
    }
}

export function loadFinished() {
    return {
        type: 'LOAD_FINISHED'
    }
}

export const signOut = userAuthParams => (
    {
        type: 'SIGN_OUT'
    }
);

export const firstLogin = userAuthParams => (
    {
        type: 'FIRST_LOGIN'
    }
);

export const fbLogin = userAuthParams => (
    {
        type: 'FB_LOGIN'
    }
);
```

process Reducer:

```js
const isLoading = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'START_LOADING':
            return 1;
        case 'END_LOADING':
            return 0
        default:
            return 0

    }
}

export default isLoading
```

isLogged Reducer

```js
const isLogged = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            return 2;
        case 'LOAD_FINISHED':
            return 1   
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            return -1 
        case 'FIRST_LOGIN':
            return 3  
        case 'FB_LOGIN':
            return 4  
        default:
            return 0

    }
}

export default isLogged
```

root Reducer:

```js
import isLogged from './IsLoggedReducer'
import process from './ProcessReducer'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    isLogged: isLogged,
    processState: process
})


export default allReducers
```

store

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import allReducers from './index'
const store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
export default store
```

Mapping state and actions to props

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { processState, isLogged} = state
  return { processState, isLogged }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      //loadFinished: () => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_FINISHED' })
      startProcess: bindActionCreators(start, dispatch),
      endProcess: bindActionCreators(stop, dispatch),
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReportStickerStatus);
```

When I dispatch startProcess my app got redirected to a empty page

THERES NO ANY ERRORS ON CONSOLE

**UPDATE [ SOLVED ]**

I had to return the state in each action, even in default

```js
import initialState from './initialState'

const isLogged = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: 2
            };
        case 'LOAD_FINISHED':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: 1
            };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: -1
            };
        case 'FIRST_LOGIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: 3
            };
        case 'FB_LOGIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: 4
            };
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            };
    }
}

export default isLogged
```

Comment: The code you shared is functional and will work. The issue you are having is probably related to some other part of your code. Maybe someone can help if you share the code of the component you are rendering, including how you call `startProcess`

Comment: Thanks, i solve the error by changing my reducer, checkout the update above